# Interleave two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I try to shuffle two array with return type integer. For example, I have {1, 2, 3} and {0, 5}. The result I get was {1,0}. So, I'm not sure how would I print the rest of numbers in array.

Here is what I have:

```
public int[] shuffle(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int shuff = 0;
    int[] out = { A[shuff], B[shuff] };

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
            int shuffle = A[i];
            A[i] = B[j];
            B[j] = shuffle;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I don't think you can call it "shuffle".. shuffle is something random you just switch position if i readed the code correctly

Comment: The result I want is {1,0,2,5,3}

Comment: "Interleave" might be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
int[] out = { A[shuff], B[shuff] };
```

you are just putting first number of A and first number of B, your loop doesn't matter at all. Then you return out, so it's going to always return `{1,0}`

If you expect result as: `{1, 0, 2, 5, 3}` I would write it this way:

```
public static int[] interleave(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] out = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int j = 0;
    int maxLength = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        if (i < a.length) {
            out[j++] = a[i];
        }
        if (i < b.length) {
            out[j++] = b[i];
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Run snippet:
http://rextester.com/ISTE29382

Comment: Allthough it is correct, this is more of a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Edited, added sample solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic solution:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
     Integer []a={1, 2, 3},b= {0, 5};
     System.out.println(interweave(Arrays.asList(a),Arrays.asList(b)));
}
public static <t> List<t> interweave(List<t> ... lists) {
    int max=0,sum=0;
    for(List<t> l:lists){
        assert l!=null;
        if(l.size()>max){
            max=l.size();
        }
        sum+=l.size();
    }
    List<t> ret=new ArrayList<>(sum);
    for(int i=0;i<max;i++){
        for(List<t> l:lists){
            if(i<l.size()){
                ret.add(l.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```