# combine elements of two arrays "turn by turn"

Tags: java, arrays

I want to combine elements of two arrays **"turn by turn"**.

result must be: [a,1,b,2,c,3,d,4,e,5]

```
    int[] mas1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
    String[] mas2 ={"a","b","c","d","e"};

    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i = 0; i <mas1.length ; i++) {
        System.out.print(mas2[i]+","+mas1[i]+",");

    }
    System.out.println("]");
```

It`s working. But is there another smart way to realize it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interleave two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733806/interleave-two-arrays)

Comment: @Adi219 i dont need to shuffle them. Just place in series, one after another.

Comment: The dupe isn't about shuffling, it's about interleaving the two arrays (which is what you're trying to do here).

Comment: @Adi219 the end result here is to print the content of the arrays (or perhaps to generate a string of them) and not to combine them into a new array as I understand it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm not an expert in Java, but I'm fairly certain that OP could just print the new array and get the desired result (as would happen in python)

Comment: @Adi219 True but creating a new array just to print it doesn’t seem like an improvement to the original code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You're right, but tbh the question doesn't seem appropriate for this site (I'd have thought codereview would suit it better)

Comment: Not sure what you consider "smarter" but one simple change is to loop to `length - 1` instead and print the last pair of items after the for loop so you can avoid that trailing `, `

Comment: Do you want a new array of Strings with the interchanged elements, or to just print the elements of 2 lists interchangeably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the stream api, you could flatMap the both into one by index. Below solution depends on both arrays having the same size

```
int[] mas1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
String[] mas2 ={"a","b","c","d","e"};
String[] combined = IntStream.range(0, mas1.length)
        .boxed()
        .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(mas2[i], String.valueOf(mas1[i])))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

If you want to keep types, you can stream to an object array too

```
Object[] combined = IntStream.range(0, mas1.length)
        .boxed()
        .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(mas2[i], mas1[i]))
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a new combined array of `String` type then you can check below,
please note array stores elements of the same type  (for Arrays class use: import java.util.Arrays;)

```
    int[] mas1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    String[] mas2 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

    String[] combinedArray = new String[mas1.length + mas2.length];

    int mas1_index = 0;
    int mas2_index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < combinedArray.length; i++) {

        if (i % 2 == 0&&mas2_index<mas2.length) {
                combinedArray[i] = mas2[mas2_index++];
        } else if(mas1_index <mas1.length ) {
                combinedArray[i] = Integer.toString(mas1[mas1_index++]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combinedArray)); // output -> [a, 1, b, 2, c, 3, d, 4, e, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bambam has proposed some really good solutions and I would definitely apply one of them, if what you want always has to do with 2 same-sized arrays.

However, in case you want two have to different-sized arrays and independent of their type, you could use a solution similar to this:

```
public List<String> addRecursively(int index, Object[] array1, Object[] array2, List<String> list){
    if(index < array1.length)
        list.add(String.valueOf(array1[index]));
    if(index < array2.length)
        list.add(String.valueOf(array2[index]));
    if(index >= array1.length && index >= array2.length)
        return list;

    return addRecursively(index+1, array1, array2, list);
}
```

Here is an example of how to use this method:

```
Integer[] arrayOfIntegers = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5};
String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"};
List<String> unified = addRecursively(0,arrayOfStrings,arrayOfIntegers,new ArrayList<String>);

//output = a1b2c3d4e5f6g
for(String str:unified) System.out.print(str)
//output = [a, 1, b, 2, c, 3, d, 4, e, 5, f, 6, g]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: You cannot use primitive types with this method. You arrays need to have *wrapped* primitive data types, something achieved with [boxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418296/what-does-it-mean-to-say-a-type-is-boxed).
If your arrays are  already instantiated as primitive types, you could convert them in Java 8 like this:

```
int [] primitive = //some value here;
Integer[] wrapped = IntStream.of(primitive).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

And you could definitely use a HashMap like the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/709973/8075923) and implement it in the aforementioned method.

I hope everyone finds this answer simple and comprehensible.